# Where can I configure/define delivery agent "F=" flags for sendmail?

Tags: email-server, sendmail

As per [this source](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/sendmail-4th-edition/9780596510299/ch20s08.html), I'm aware that Sendmail has the ability to set/define delivery agent flags (for example `F=0` to turn off MX lookups for delivery agent).

Where are these set? Can I define these in the `sendmail.mc` file?

Answer (score 1):

You can

- modify flags of mailers provided by mc files of sendmail.org using 
  [MODIFY_MAILER_FLAGS](https://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/m4/ostype.html#MODIFY_MAILER_FLAGS) in sendmail.mc file
- define your own mailer "from scratch" using `MAILER_DEFINITIONS` in sendmail.mc
- "clone & modify" mailer/*.m4 files provided in sendmail distribution